# GKE cluster failed to load

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhwuV.png)

---

when I click on culster name on GCP console not able to look into cluster details. is shows failed to load message

Answer (score 0):

Customer projects should contain one or more of the following accounts:

Editor:

`project_id@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`

Kubernetes Engine Service Agent:

`service-project_id@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Check your permissions in order to look into your cluster details.